# React useEffect Execution Order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I have a snippet of code that uses two components - `C1` and `C2`:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from 'react';

const C1 = ({ children }) => {
  console.log('1');
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('2');
  }, []);
 
  return <>{children}</>;
};
 
const C2 = () => {
  console.log('3');//
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('4');
  }, []);
 
  return <div>YOWZA</div>;
};
 

export default function App() {
  return (<C1>
    <C2/>
  </C1>)
}
```

I am trying to understand the order of components render. The console shows order like this:

`1 1 3 3 4 2 4 2`

I do not understand why 1 and 3 were shown twice. Also, why 4 and 2 are shown twice if they do not re-render on component update?

Comment: in dev env, strict mode "render" each components twice. Just remember this

Comment: so without it, should it be 1,3,4,2?

Comment: Yes, indeed. You can verify a simple one here https://jsfiddle.net/u7nzqvrj/